# mysql: count total, unique, returning users

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE zoom
    (`id` int, `fb_id` int, `date` datetime);

INSERT INTO zoom
    (`id`, `fb_id`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1123, '2009-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1145, '2009-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1123, '2009-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1198, '2009-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1176, '2009-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (6, 1176, '2009-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (7, 1123, '2009-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (8, 1177, '2009-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (9, 1200, '2009-01-03 00:00:00');
```

And this is my mysql code that I have until this moment:

```
SELECT count(Znew.fb_id) as totalUsers,
count(Zold.fb_id) as returningUsers,
count(Znew.fb_id) - count(Zold.fb_id) as uniqueUsers,
DATE_FORMAT(Znew.date, '%d %b %y') as zoom
FROM zoom Znew
LEFT JOIN zoom Zold
ON Zold.date < Znew.date
AND Zold.fb_id = Znew.fb_id
GROUP BY Znew.date;
```

After I run the above code I get this result:

```
totalUsers  returningUsers  uniqueUsers zoom
    2             0              2      01 Jan 09
    3             1              2      02 Jan 09
    5             3              2      03 Jan 09
```

In the above result only the first two rows are correct, so basically my mysql code works only for 2 GROUPS, the third row is obviously wrong.

Here is the correct result that I am expecting after I run the code:

```
totalUsers  returningUsers  uniqueUsers zoom
    2             0              2      01 Jan 09
    3             1              2      02 Jan 09
    4             2              2      03 Jan 09
```

Any thoughts?
sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5e2a/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing some `DISTINCT` keywords here and there.

```
SELECT count(distinct Znew.fb_id) as totalUsers,
count(distinct Zold.fb_id) as returningUsers,
count(distinct Znew.fb_id) - count(distinct Zold.fb_id) as uniqueUsers,
DATE_FORMAT(Znew.date, '%d %b %y') as zoom
FROM zoom Znew
LEFT JOIN zoom Zold
ON Zold.date < Znew.date
AND Zold.fb_id = Znew.fb_id
GROUP BY Znew.date;
```